# Windows defender молча удаляет файлы

Tags: windows, windows-10, антивирус, defender

Как настроить Windows Defender таким образом, чтобы если он видит подозрительный файл, он спрашивал, что с ним делать, а не удалял и не отправлял в карантин по-тихому?

Comment: Это не оно? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/configure-remediation-windows-defender-antivirus "Turn off routine remediation"

Comment: @Eleferen, похоже...

Comment: @Eleferen, так себе... Теперь файлы исчезают, но не в журнал, а на одно окно поближе..